# React : "DOMException: String contains an invalid character" error while encoding in base64

Tags: javascript, reactjs, utf-8, base64

I'm facing a new kind of error and I'm kind of stuck here. I have a lightweight code editor in my app and I send its content (typed by the user) to my back-end, encoding it in base64.
First I used `codeContent.toString("base64");` method and it worked like a charm with this kind of testing content :

```js
let numberTest = 52;
let arrayTest = [63, 24, 75];
let sumTest = numberTest + arrayTest[0];
```

The problem here, is that I can't decode it back to UTF-8 when I want to retrieve this code from my API, I get some gibberish.

So I tried this method instead : `atob(codeContent);`. In this case, if I type a simple text like : `test`, the encoded version looks fine (`µë-`), but the content is still empty in my backend after my POST. And if I try this with a simple line of JS like `let testNumber = 52;`, then I get this error : "DOMException: String contains an invalid character"

To sum it up : I'm a little lost, what's the good way to encode my text to base64 and retrieve it afterwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I understood atob and btoa wrong : I thought **b**toa decoded FROM base64, but it's the other way around.
So, encoding TO base64 :

```js
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
```

And decoding base64 :

```js
decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
```